# How to manage your jQuery library in your web site?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web-inspector

I’m `NEW` to the web world. Well, 'Every artist was once an amateur' - right ?.

I am asking for your kindly advice.

Every-time I want to integrate new feature into my site , it never work ! :( 
For Example, I found a small feature that I like from other site like [this](http://www.datatables.net), or [this](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/input-file-popover-preview-image).

In order to make them work, mostly, we need to include a certain jQuery library in our head section like so ..

```
<head>
<script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

OR

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
```

But even if I did that It doesn’t seem to work.

I’m `suspicious` that I have include more than one library and that could possibly lead to override.
Is there a way to check which library `include` get `use` and which `include` are `useless`using web inspector ? OR anything like that ?

`HUGE` appreciation for someone who involve on this post !

Comment: Does your console report errors? For example, if your in chrome: CTRL+SHIFT+I and then the tab "Console". It could be the error lays somewhere else than the script inclusion

Comment: So don't include two jQuery files. One is more than enough.

Comment: @WesselvanderLinden : So after you find that, what next should you do ?

Comment: Simply including jquery won't add any functionality to your website, you need to include the respective plugin as well, and initialize it. For that, you should go through it's documentation...

Comment: @evoque2015 , i love your way to explain the question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One jquery library is enough, you do not need more, also, if you see a feature on a website and you see that website using a different library version than yours it doesn't mean that you have to include that one too one is enough. You also might want to add the .ui version of the library because some features will not work without the UI since they use banckground animations and other stuff.

Comment: I see. Thanks for clarify. You mention add the UI Version. How do I add a UI version and maintain to have only one jQuery library. Can you please give me one example ? I'm trying to get a precise understanding of these things. Thanks again.

Comment: Well, I for example have only jquery-1.9.1 and jquery-ui-1.9.1. And when you see a snippet/feature that you want to integrate in a website, you download the files and add to your js/css folders only the feature's custom files, then call them into your script.

Comment: Precisely. Thanks Alin.

Comment: You are welcome, my friend, hope this helps and happy coding.